# Dealing with view specific properties of a Resource in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, viewmodel

Lets say we have a Rest resource that looks like this:

```
{
    "orderId" : 123
    "details" : [
         {"detailId":555,...more attribs},
         ...more details
    ]
}
```

In my view, I want to hold extra state for the order details, eg. isHidden, isExpanded etc.

I could add those to the detail object once the resource is fetched from the server.
But that would make those view specific properties go along with the resource when I post it back to the server to save it.
Making the json deserialize on the backend crash..

I've experimented with view specific properties that start with $$, which angular will remove when it jsonifies the resource.
That works, but those properties are not included in the digest cycle so changing those doesnt trigger an update of the view.

I've also experimented with nested controllers and keeping those view properties in the detail controller.. which works fine..
That does however make it harder to set up the views when the resource is loaded, I can not modify those view properties in the root controller since the details does not yet have a controller assigned to them..

Another posibillity would be to wrap the resource in a specific view model that keeps these properties. but that requires a bit more coding and mapping.

How do you guys deal with this kind of problems??

Comment: What would use case be for those properties? Can usually store what is needed in directive scopes and/or services without affecting the main data

Comment: e.g. expanding/collapsing view elements, changing view colors etc for specific items. presentation stuff, that don't actually belong to the resource beeing presented

Comment: Well one thing to keep in mind is that for `ng-repeat` a child scope gets created for every repeated element in the array. So that can make storing instance data fairly easy in a directive scope. Hard to get more granular without more real world situations

Comment: Yes, but that data is not available to you when the resource is fetched from the server, since ng-repeat have not yet rendered the details.. so I can not initialize data in childscopes before they exist..

Comment: Can't do much to help without some code examples of what you are trying to do